# Calculate angle to launch projectile to reach target

Tags: game-physics

I have a ball at (-1188, 100, 0) and need to calculate the angle at which it must be launched to reach (1188, 0, 0) at 1700p/s (points per second). Only force acting on the ball is gravity. No air drag is modeled at this point. Gravity is 980p/s.

I'm encountering an accuracy error where the ball is still high when x = 1188, roughly 90 points higher than target position to be more precise.

This is how I calculate the launch angle given desired speed, target vector and gravity:

```
func strike(speed: Float, target: SCNVector3, gravity: Float) {

    //Get ball's body
    let body = self.component(ofType: BallBodyComponent.self)!.ballBody

    //Vector from ball to target in the court
    var toTarget = target - body.position

    //Elevation difference
    let yOffset = (target - body.position).y

    //Clear out vertical component to end up with planar vector
    toTarget.y = 0

    //Get distance in x-z plane
    let distance = toTarget.length()

    //Launch angle will be stored here
    var angle: Float = 0

    if self.launchAngle(speed: speed, distance: distance, yOffset: yOffset, gravity: gravity, angle: &angle) {
        body.setStrike(speed: speed, angle: angle, forwardDirection: toTarget.normalized())
    }

}

func launchAngle(speed: Float, distance: Float, yOffset: Float, gravity: Float, angle: inout Float, useLowAngle: Bool = true) -> Bool {
    angle = 0

    let speedSquared = speed * speed
    let operandA = powf(speed, 4)
    let operandB = gravity * (gravity * (distance * distance) + (2 * yOffset * speedSquared))

    if operandB > operandA {
        return false
    }

    let root = sqrt(operandA - operandB)

    let angle0 = atan2(speedSquared + root, gravity * distance)
    let angle1 = atan2(speedSquared - root, gravity * distance)

    if angle0 > 0 && angle1 > 0 {
        angle = useLowAngle ? min(angle0, angle1) : max(angle0, angle1)
    } else if angle0 < 0 && angle1 < 0 {
        angle = 0
    } else if angle0 < 0 {
        angle = angle1
    } else {
        angle = angle0
    }

    return true
}
```

Ball's set strike method is simple:

```
func setStrike(speed: Float, angle: Float, forwardDirection: SCNVector3) {
    self.angle = angle
    self.speed = speed
    self.forwardDirection = forwardDirection
    self.positionOnStrike = self.position
}
```

Ball's update method takes time of travel since hit and gravity = 980p/s is passed:

```
func update(time: Float, gravity: Float) {
    let verticalDisplacement = ((self.speed * sin(self.angle)) * time) - (0.5 * gravity * time * time)
    let forwardDisplacement = self.forwardDirection * (self.speed * cos(self.angle)) * time
    self.position = self.positionOnStrike + SCNVector3(x: forwardDisplacement.x, y: verticalDisplacement, z: forwardDisplacement.z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was almost right, except that the target position had wrong y component. I modified it so y is at ground level and now it's working as expected.